# cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, package.json

I am working on integrating a package library named A with another package(website) named B , but in A I was getting error where it says cannot be used as a JSX component

I was be able to solve this issue by updating A package json with:

"resolutions": { "@types/react": "17.0.14", "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14" }
and also added preinstall in scripts: "preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"

This resolved the issue, but every time I change A package which is a dependency of B, I have to remove node_modules and package-lock to have a successful build and see the new changes in B which I think it is weird anyone has any idea? here are the package.json s A, package.json

here are the package.json s

A package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build-storybook": "NODE_ENV=production build-storybook -c cfg/storybook -o dist/storybook",
    "build:webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "lint:fix": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx src",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx src",
    "posttest": "generate-coverage-data",
    "prepublish": "npm run typescript",
    "preinstall": "([ ! -f package-lock.json ] && npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts --no-audit); npx force-resolutions",
    "release": "rm -rf dist && tsc --p tsconfig-cjs.json && npm run build",
    "scaffold": "./scripts/scaffold.sh",
    "storybook:build": "build-storybook -c ./storybook-config -o
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "typescript": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "typescript-release": "tsc --p tsconfig-cjs.json"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.7",
    "emotion": "^10.0.27",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "is-hotkey": "^0.1.8",
    "is-url": "^1.2.4",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.differenceby": "^4.8.0",
    "lodash.escaperegexp": "^4.1.2",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.uniqueid": "^4.0.1",
    "npm": "^8.19.2",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.107.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "slate": "^0.60.8",
    "slate-history": "^0.59.0",
    "slate-react": "^0.60.8"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.7",
    "i18next": "^19.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/helper-validator-identifier": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.0.26",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.26",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.7",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.8",
    "@types/is-url": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.differenceby": "^4.8.6",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.isempty": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.5",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/lodash.sortby": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/storybook-react-router": "^1.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.19",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "eslint": "7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.9",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.7",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "globby": "^8.0.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-when": "^3.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "react-to-typescript-definitions": "^1.2.0",
    "storybook-react-router": "^1.0.8",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "npm-pretty-much": {
    "publishDir": "",
    "runRelease": "always"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
}
```

B package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "files": [],
  "scripts": {
    "check-types": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "cypress": "cypress install && cypress run --env configFile=dev",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open --env configFile=dev",
    "cypress-beta": "cypress install && cypress info && cypress run --env configFile=beta || (npm run postcypress ; exit 1)",
    "cypress-beta:open": "cypress open --env configFile=beta",
    "cypress-gamma": "cypress install && cypress run --env configFile=gamma || (npm run postcypress ; exit 1)",
    "cypress-gamma:open": "cypress open --env configFile=gamma",
    "postcypress": "npm run merge-reports",
    "posttest": "if command -v generate-coverage-data >/dev/null 2>&1; then generate-coverage-data; fi",
    "merge-reports": "node ./scripts/merge-reports.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf $(readlink build) && rm -rf build coverage",
    "createmons": "createmons",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx src",
    "lint-fix": "eslint -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx src",
    "lint-fix-prettier": "npm run lint-fix && npm run prettier",
    "listcloudformationoutputs": "listcloudformationoutputs",
    "build": "npm run lint-fix-prettier && NODE_ENV=production webpack --config configuration/webpack.config && node ./configuration/prepare-cdk-files",
    "server": "SERVER_MODE=standalone webpack serve --config configuration/webpack.config",
    "mons-server": "webpack serve --config configuration/webpack.config",
    "secure-mons-server": "webpack serve --config configuration/webpack.config --https --key ~/cert/keyFile.key --cert ~/cert/certFile.crt",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "prettier": "./node_modules/.bin/prettier --write 'src/**/*@(.js|.ts|.tsx)'",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect --trace-warnings node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:strict": "node --trace-warnings --unhandled-rejections=strict node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "browser-test": "katal-integration-test --nightwatchBaseConfig browser-tests/nightwatch/nightwatch.base.json",
    "browser-test-regenerate-screenshots": "REGENERATE_SCREENSHOTS=1 npm run browser-test -- --url http://$(hostname):4321",
    "browser-test-local": "npm run browser-test -- --url http://$(hostname):4321",
    "browser-test-beta-na": "npm run browser-test -- --url https://rainier-m1k.integ.amazon.com/colombiasampleapp/index.html --materialSetName katal.integration.credentials.betaEMCTestAccount --merchantId A2KAGNIRNSGDD --marketplaceId ATVPDKIKX0DER [this is an example. use your own app url]",
    "browser-test-beta-eu": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName katal.integration.credentials.betaEMCTestAccount",
    "browser-test-beta-fe": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-beta-cn": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here]--materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-gamma-na": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-gamma-eu": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-gamma-fe": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-gamma-cn": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-prod-na": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here]--materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-prod-eu": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-prod-fe": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]",
    "browser-test-prod-cn": "npm run browser-test -- --url [url here] --materialSetName [material set here]"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.1.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.12.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.34",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "4.2.4",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.628.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.9.0",
    "cross-fetch": "3.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cypress": "^7.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "emotion": "^10.0.27",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "eslint": "7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "husky": "^2.4.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.9",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-icu": "^2.0.0",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "intl-messageformat": "^9.4.7",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "junit-report-merger": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.8",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.13.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "mochawesome": "^3.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^1.0.7",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5",
    "nightwatch": "^1.5.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.107.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "otpauth": "^7.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.1.0",
    "postcss-custom-media": "8.0.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.6.0",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.7",
    "react-intl": "^5.12.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "react-transition-group": "4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tachyons": "^7.0.1-5",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  }
}
```

will appreciate your help

Comment: instead of npm i do npm ci

Comment: using npm ci I get `npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json`

Answer (score 4):

Try without using `npm-force-resolutions` by using the native npm field, [which is `overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides), not `resolutions`.

```js
  "overrides": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
```

If that doesn't help, your best bet is probably to transition to `Yarn@1.x`, where I've never had the problem you're describing despite using Yarn's `resolutions` *a lot*.